# mistake when exporting numpy data to csv to pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, python, csv

I have to plot data from a numerical simulation. I perform my simulations with `python` and `numpy`. But now I want to plot the result in a LaTeX file. Since I want to be able to modify the layout without rerun the simulation, I think that exporting my results in a `csv` file then read this file in `pgfplots` is a good solution. Unfortunately, when I do this I obtain different results than when I plot with `matplotlib` for example.

Here is what I obtain from `matplotlib`:
[image: Matplotlib result]

And here is what I obtain with `pgfplots`:
[image: pgfplots result]

The `pgfplots` result has been generated with the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}                       % 
\usepackage{pgfplots}                   %
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}         %


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[colormap/viridis,
                enlarge y limits=false,
                axis equal image,
                axis on top,
                colorbar,
            ]           

        \addplot[ 
                matrix plot*, point meta=explicit, mesh/cols=10,
            ]
            table[x=y, y=x, 
                meta=T, ignore chars={\#}, col sep=comma,
                ] 
            {hydrostat.csv};

    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the file `hydrostat.csv` can be obtained through this link:
https://transfernow.net/103fg0a2hl44

This file has been generated from the `numpy` as `np` command (where `T1` is output field, `X` and `Y` are the coordinates, `ly` and `ly` are the dimensions of the mesh):

```
np.savetxt('./hydrostat.csv', np.column_stack(( np.reshape(X, (lx*ly,1)), np.reshape(Y, (lx*ly,1)), np.reshape(T1, (lx*ly,1))  )), header='x, y, T', comments='# ',delimiter=',', newline='\n' )
```

I think it is not a big deal, just a wrong configuration of `pgfplots`, but I can not find it.

It looks like there a miss number of rows and columns, so I tried to change `mesh/cols` values but the results where worst. I also try stuff like export from `matplotlib` in `pgf` format but it creates a `png` image so there no way to change to layout without rerun the simulation. The same is happening with `matplotlib2tikz`.

Thank you in advance for helping to find my mistake.

Comment: Does adding `colormap/viridis` to the options of the axis help?

Comment: My problem is not about the `colormap`, but about the organization of the results. Look around the line 5 for example you go from yellowish to blue and line 6 from blue to yellowish. This is not comparable with the line or column 5 of `matplotlib` results. I thinks that line 5 and 6 from `pgfplots` should in fact be only one.

Comment: I had a quick look at the data file. The y values run all the way up to 20. This is consistent with the plot produced by pgfplots but not at all with your first plot *unless* you exchange the roles of x and y there. Is that what's going on?

Comment: I think this is part of the problem. But I switch the value of x and y in the reading of the table with the command : `table[x=y, y=x,...` with or without change of the `mesh/rows` value, and the problem mention remains.

Comment: @marmot, I edit my question according to your comments. I hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: To me it looks as if you have transposed the data for some reason. That is, I fail to see that pgfplots is the culprit. BTW, the code formatting got destroyed in your edit.

Comment: Okay, there is something I do not understand. Following your remark, I just transpose the data in numpy before to export with `np.reshape(T1.T, (lx*ly,1))`and I get something closer to the expected result. I do not understand why I have to transpose the field and not the coordinates... I let you write an answer.

Comment: I don't think I am qualified to write an answer because I have no clue whatsoever about numpy. So you could write your own answer or we just wait till someone with the corresponding expertise shows up to write something. (I am glad, though, that your problem seems to got solved. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short version

Thanks to the comments of marmot, we could determine that part of the problem comes from the original data in the `csv` file.

The problem can be solved by using the `numpy/python` command to export the data `T1` :

```
np.savetxt('./hydrostat.csv', np.column_stack(( np.reshape(X, (lx*ly,1)), np.reshape(Y, (lx*ly,1)), np.reshape(T1.T, (lx*ly,1))  )), header='x, y, T', comments='# ',delimiter=',', newline='\n' )
```

Please note the presence of the data transposed with the `T1.T`.

The last point is to use `y dir=reverse` to obtain the wanted output with `pgfplots`.

### Long version

If I use the `numpy/python` code to export the data (without transpose):

```
np.savetxt('./hydrostat.csv', np.column_stack(( np.reshape(X, (lx*ly,1)), np.reshape(Y, (lx*ly,1)),  np.reshape(T1, (lx*ly,1))  )), header='x, y, T', comments='# ',delimiter=',', newline='\n' )
```

I obtain the following file `hydrostat.csv` present in the question link or in the answer of Ulrich.

Then by using the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}                       % 
\usepackage{pgfplots}                   %
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}         %


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[colormap/viridis,
                enlarge y limits=false,
                axis equal image,
                axis on top,
                colorbar,
                y dir=reverse,
            ]           

        \addplot[ 
                matrix plot*, point meta=explicit, mesh/cols=10,
            ]
            table[x expr=\thisrow{x}, y expr=\thisrow{y}, 
                            meta=T, ignore chars={\#}, col sep=comma,
                 ] 
            {hydrostat.csv};

    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I will obtain the resulting picture:[image]

I added a red circle to highlight the problem. Even if the apsect ration is the inverse of the one wanted (this can be solve by using the solution of Ulrich), in this area data are different from the `matplotlib` picture.

Then if I use the `numpy/python` code (with the transpose):

```
np.savetxt('./hydrostat.csv', np.column_stack(( np.reshape(X, (lx*ly,1)), np.reshape(Y, (lx*ly,1)),  np.reshape(T1.T, (lx*ly,1))  )), header='x, y, T', comments='# ',delimiter=',', newline='\n' )
```

I will obtain the file `hydrostat.csv`:

```
# x, y, T
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.665274928193408721e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.663971023015621276e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.664437620670988771e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.665301707977002721e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.666191243753081253e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.667140894072094426e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.668030901761194951e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.668895764592672748e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.669363119300035780e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.000000000000000000e+00,6.668059134476984617e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.664984000034479550e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.663563233698642785e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.664214191117951991e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.665131018225954884e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.666140120616599329e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.667192060591138336e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.668201621659066713e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.669119206097180452e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.669770941226786931e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,2.000000000000000000e+00,6.668350157237450393e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.664854791213135066e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.663415913719938910e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.664222063383633543e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.665140801477354993e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.666148761882257912e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.667183640856011451e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.668191978934161490e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.669111359852449850e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.669918243907704269e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,3.000000000000000000e+00,6.668479455078759610e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.664815006196560532e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.663330228538590916e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.664169300798881146e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.665119589458776694e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.666143422671383378e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.667189113521675425e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.668213283281555492e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.669164154775901743e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.670003945605174067e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,4.000000000000000000e+00,6.668519314279444110e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.664770000644588688e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.663251033169389492e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.664111506008371100e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.665088727699410853e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.666133511753929985e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.667199070068153821e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.668244175028308351e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.669221964566964811e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.670083158660570222e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,5.000000000000000000e+00,6.668564335409302712e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.664730997869784401e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.663180845314861100e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.664054966081143228e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.665054530423857315e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.666122244948706754e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.667210326937413889e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.668278363313814294e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.669278502659713448e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.670153355264032413e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,6.000000000000000000e+00,6.668603341518074545e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.664697463550552925e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.663120196443859111e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.664004262050575722e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.665021952648533254e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.666111123890067214e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.667221413104018612e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.668310914276506240e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.669329195149436007e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.670214007442626380e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,7.000000000000000000e+00,6.668636878941709423e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.664671553565268969e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.663072476998228577e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.663962705305201961e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.664994244361608366e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.666101447363657062e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.667231048960070572e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.668338591735474274e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.669370737822977180e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.670261728290619585e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,8.000000000000000000e+00,6.668662792153110530e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.664654603829183177e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.663040583623929258e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.663933804084154477e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.664974447369693689e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.666094420860504410e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.667238041750613853e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.668358363404600642e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.669399627501244598e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.670293622727493377e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,9.000000000000000000e+00,6.668679744632736162e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.664646443897686012e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.663024890447618587e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.663919082297593555e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.664964158667143757e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.666090728974014556e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.667241714870277836e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.668368638159816175e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.669414343107787913e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.670309316686268142e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.000000000000000000e+01,6.668687906109909136e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.664646443897686012e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.663024890447619697e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.663919082297594665e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.664964158667143757e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.666090728974012336e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.667241714870280056e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.668368638159817285e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.669414343107786802e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.670309316686269252e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.100000000000000000e+01,6.668687906109908026e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.664654603829183177e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.663040583623929258e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.663933804084154477e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.664974447369693689e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.666094420860504410e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.667238041750613853e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.668358363404600642e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.669399627501244598e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.670293622727493377e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.200000000000000000e+01,6.668679744632737272e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.664671553565266748e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.663072476998227467e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.663962705305200851e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.664994244361608366e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.666101447363657062e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.667231048960070572e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.668338591735474274e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.669370737822977180e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.670261728290620695e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.300000000000000000e+01,6.668662792153110530e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.664697463550550705e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.663120196443860221e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.664004262050573502e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.665021952648533254e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.666111123890067214e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.667221413104018612e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.668310914276506240e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.669329195149436007e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.670214007442625270e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.400000000000000000e+01,6.668636878941707202e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.664730997869783291e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.663180845314862211e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.664054966081143228e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.665054530423855095e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.666122244948704534e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.667210326937413889e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.668278363313813184e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.669278502659714558e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.670153355264032413e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.500000000000000000e+01,6.668603341518071215e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.664770000644588688e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.663251033169390602e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.664111506008372210e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.665088727699408633e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.666133511753928875e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.667199070068152711e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.668244175028308351e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.669221964566965921e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.670083158660571332e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.600000000000000000e+01,6.668564335409303823e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.664815006196560532e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.663330228538593136e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.664169300798881146e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.665119589458776694e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.666143422671384489e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.667189113521674315e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.668213283281555492e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.669164154775902853e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.670003945605175177e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.700000000000000000e+01,6.668519314279444110e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.664854791213135066e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.663415913719941130e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.664222063383633543e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.665140801477353882e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.666148761882257912e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.667183640856010340e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.668191978934161490e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.669111359852450960e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.669918243907705380e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.800000000000000000e+01,6.668479455078759610e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.664984000034481770e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.663563233698643895e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.664214191117953101e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.665131018225954884e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.666140120616598219e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.667192060591137226e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.668201621659067824e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.669119206097181562e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.669770941226791372e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,1.900000000000000000e+01,6.668350157237451503e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.665274928193409831e-01
2.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.663971023015621276e-01
3.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.664437620670989881e-01
4.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.665301707977003831e-01
5.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.666191243753081253e-01
6.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.667140894072093316e-01
7.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.668030901761193840e-01
8.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.668895764592674968e-01
9.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.669363119300038001e-01
1.000000000000000000e+01,2.000000000000000000e+01,6.668059134476987948e-01
```

Then by using the LaTeX code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}                       % 
\usepackage{pgfplots}                   %
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}         %


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[colormap/viridis,
                enlarge y limits=false,
                axis equal image,
                axis on top,
                colorbar,
                y dir=reverse,
            ]           

        \addplot[ 
                matrix plot*, point meta=explicit, mesh/cols=10,
            ]
            table[x expr=\thisrow{y}, y expr=\thisrow{x}, 
                            meta=T, ignore chars={\#}, col sep=comma,
                 ] 
            {hydrostat.csv};

    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I finally obtain the wanted result:[image]